# Regex lookahead+lookbehind OR instead of AND

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-look-ahead

so I have this regex:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])(0)(?![a-zA-Z])
```

it caches "0"s that don't have a letter before AND no letter after

I want to catch "0"s that either don't have a letter before OR don't have a letter after.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/h3CTaC/1)

Comment: Use `0(?!(?<=[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the OR operator `|`:

`(?<!\w)0|0(?!\w)`

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/spr1JP/1)